# Round within the vim expression register

Tags: vim

Is it possible to round within vim's expression register? I want to do something like the following:

```
<C-R>=1*round(1.0/7,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ceil()` function rounds the given expression up, `floor()` rounds down, and `round()` rounds to the nearest integer. All of these return floats.  If you want to round to two decimal places, then multiply and divide by 100, as in `round(x * 100) / 100`.

For more information, try `:h eval`

Comment: I'd guess the second argument is supposed to cut off the rounding at two decimals, rather than an integer. So if you want to achieve this you could multiply by 100, round and then divide by 100

Comment: I assume that the ",2" means the number of decimal places, which you can achieve with `round(x * 100) / 100`.

Comment: @benjifisher yea that's correct. If you add an answer I'll mark it ;). Too bad there isn't a more concise way

Comment: @benjifisher In Python, you could type `round(1.0/7, 2)`, in vim, you have to resort to `round(1.0/7 * 100) * 0.01`.